# Humility of Yoktan

Tags: rashi, parashat-noach

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.10.25?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.10.25.2&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) (Bereishis 10:25)  mentions the humility of Yoktan allowed him to merit 13 out of 70 nations.

> ויקטן. שֶׁהָיָה עָנָו וּמַקְטִין עַצְמוֹ, לְכָךְ זָכָה לְהַעֲמִיד כָּל
>   הַמִּשְׁפָּחוֹת הַלָּלוּ׃
>
> יקטן JOKTAN — He was so called (“the little one”) because he was so
>   humble and thought little (ומקטין) of himself; therefore he merited
>   the privilege of rearing all these families (Genesis Rabbah 37:7)

What did Yoktan do that showed his humility?

Comment: Checked the Midrash. Didn't provide any new information.

Comment: The Midrash says שהיה מקטין את עסקיו @ezra some new information.

Comment: [Sefer HaYashar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_haYashar_(midrash)) says he was named so signifying the “shortened” lifespan which occurred in his time.

Comment: @oliver doesn’t really Addres the op

Comment: Hence it’s a comment (to indicate that there are alternative Midrashim/reasons).

Answer (score 1):

Rashi is quoting Bereshit Rabbah 37:7 which quotes Rabbi Yossi ben Chalafta who says:

> **אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹסֵי בֶּן חֲלַפְתָּא** נָבִיא גָדוֹל הָיָה עֵבֶר שֶׁהוֹצִיא לְשֵׁם הַמְאֹרָע, הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב וּלְעֵבֶר יֻלַּד שְׁנֵי בָנִים וגו', **לָמָּה נִקְרָא שְׁמוֹ יָקְטָן, שֶׁהָיָה מַקְטִין אֶת עַצְמוֹ וְאֶת עֲסָקָיו.** וּמַה זָּכָה, **זָכָה לְהַעֲמִיד שְׁלשׁ עֶשְׂרֵה מִשְׁפָּחוֹת**. וּמָה אִם הַקָּטָן שֶׁהוּא מַקְטִין עֲסָקָיו כָּךְ, גָּדוֹל שֶׁהוּא מַקְטִין אֶת עֲסָקָיו עַל אַחַת כַּמָּה וְכַמָּה. **וְדִכְוָתָהּ (בראשית מח, יד): וַיִּשְׁלַח יִשְׂרָאֵל אֶת יְמִינוֹ וַיָּשֶׁת עַל רֹאשׁ אֶפְרַיִם וְהוּא הַצָּעִיר**, אָמַר רַבִּי הוּנָא וְכִי **מִן הַתּוֹלָדוֹת אֵין אָנוּ יוֹדְעִין שֶׁהוּא הַצָּעִיר, אֶלָּא שֶׁהָיָה מַצְעִיר אֶת עֲסָקָיו. וּמַה זָכָה, זָכָה לַבְּכוֹרָה.** וּמָה אִם **הַצָּעִיר עַל יְדֵי שֶׁהָיָה מַצְעִיר אֶת עֲסָקָיו זָכָה לַבְּכוֹרָה**, גָּדוֹל שֶׁהוּא מַצְעִיר אֶת עֲסָקָיו עַל אַחַת כַּמָּה וְכַמָּה

Several things are emphasized here. First is *reducing himself*, which is the concept of humility as Rashi mentions. But it also mentions minimizing *his involvement* (מַקְטִין אֶת עֲסָקָיו) with this world, meaning business pursuits and increasing ones involvement in learning Torah and serving G-d.

This is clarified by [Tanna D'vei Eliyahu Zuta](https://www.sefaria.org/Tanna_debei_Eliyahu_Zuta%2C_Additions_to_Seder_Eliyahu_Zuta%2C_Pirkei_Derech_Eretz.2?vhe=Tanna_deBei_Eliyahu_Zuta&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which says:

> **רבי אליעזר אומר כל העוסק בתורה לשמה זוכה לדברים הרבה ולא עוד אלא** שכל העולם כולו כדאי הוא לו נקרא ריע אהוב אוהב את המקום אוהב את הבריות משמח את המקום משמח את הבריות **ומלבשתו ענוה** ויראה ומכשרתו להיות צדיק וחסיד וישר ונאמן ומרחקתו מן החטא ומביאתו לידי זכות ונהנין ממנו עצה ותושיה בינה וגבורה שנאמר (משלי ח׳:י״ד) לי עצה ותושיה אני בינה לי גבורה **ונותנת לו מלכות וממשלה** וחקור דין ומגלין לו סודות מן השמים ורזי תורה **ונעשה כמעין המתגבר והולך וכנהר שאינו פוסק והוה צנוע וארך רוח ומוחל על עלבונו ומגדלתו ומרוממתו על כל המעשים.**

As pointed out in Bereshit Rabbah, this set up the paradigm for how Yaacov Avinu (the younger of the two brothers in comparison to Esav) and Ephraim, the younger brother of Menasheh received the blessing of Bechorah. Yaacov also had 12 sons establishing the 12 tribes (and ultimately will have the 13th tribe during the final redemption, like Yoktan).

Comment: Where in your quotations do you see the concept you describe in your final paragraph? All I see is that just like Yoktan's humility merited him 13 children, Ephraim's humility merited him the birthright. Where do you see anything about Yaakov having 13 children?

Comment: @DonielF It is a concept brought in Talmud and also from Midrash HaGadol, which I have quoted in other answers on this site. The parallel of the 13 families from Yoktan is with the 13 tribes of the Jewish people. FWIW, this is also associated with the 13 attributes of Mercy. The concept of 13 as found in Torah is an expression of how G-d is one (אחד) and also how we serve Him with love (אהבה). And this is also expressed through the concept of 'Klal' and 'Prat' like is found in the parshiyot, VaYakhel and Pekudei.

Comment: 1. It’s very nice that you quote it in other answers, but you don’t quote it in this one; you just state the idea. 2. You say “as pointed out in Bereshit Rabbah,” but this isn’t in your quote. Both of these problems could easily be fixed if you cite the source.

Comment: That's because a long explanation of that idea is a tangent not really associated to the question. It's worth mentioning only briefly because it relates to the Chumash quotation in the question. But getting into details should be in a different question.

Comment: Who said anything about details? I’m just asking for a citation.

Comment: Bereshit Rabbah 37:7 isn't specific enough for you? The quotation of Rabbi Yossi ben Chalafta is taken from there.

Comment: It’s not clear from the way this is worded, since your block quote doesn’t include that. Makes it sound like that’s all there is in 37:7, leaving a reader wondering where that bit comes from.

Answer (score 0):

*[פירוש מרי״ד על התורה](http://%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%B4%D7%93%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94)* says:  (translation: coming soon)

In essence, that through acquiring the trait of true humbleness (ענוה) one will merit to many children. [Perhaps that’s what Yoktan did]

> פרש״י שהיה עניו ומקטין עצמו, לכך זכה להעמיד כל המשפחות הללו. ומתבאר
>   מרש״י שבזכות שהאדם מקטין עצמו ואינו מתפאר במעלותיו, ובמצותיו, ובמעשים
>   טובים שעשה, ובתורתו שלמד ולימד, שהוא עניו באמת ואינו כועס, ומוחל על
>   עלבונו, ומכבד כל אדם, יזכה לבנים הרבה. והרמב״ן גילה לנו באגרתו החשובה
>   הדרך איך לינצל מכעס ומגאוה. והיי׳ כשירגיל ויתנהג תמיד לדבר כל דבריו
>   בנחת לכל אדם ובכל עת, עי״ז ינצל מן הכעס, ואז יעלה על לבו מדת הענוה,
>   ויתבשש מכל אדם, ואז ישרה עליו השכינה יעוי״ש.

Comment: What additional info. about Yaktan does this offer?

Comment: It provides details on how he may have humbled himself and the process @oliver

Comment: He may also have worked in a soup kitchen or declined honor accorded to him. But I wouldn’t know for sure bec. I don’t have a source; nor does the פירוש מרי״ד provide a source.

Comment: Unclear if they had [soup kitchens](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soup_kitchen#History) back then

Comment: Hmm, fair point. Then מרי״ד must’ve guessed right.